# Mystery note in Tommy Emmanuel's rendition of Classical Gas

Tags: guitar, technique, transcription

I'm transcribing [Tommy Emmanuel's rendition of Classical Gas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S33tWZqXhnk). At [1:19](https://youtu.be/S33tWZqXhnk?t=79), during the C chord, there is an apparent C3 sounding twice. But as can be seen in the video, he's nowhere near string 1 fret 8. I examined some harmonics available around the fingering shown in the video, but the closest thing is a C4. What really fries my brain is that it certainly doesn't sound like a harmonic. It sounds very much like string 1 fret 8. Is this being caused by a resonance in his particular guitar, or is there some trick he's employing that I'm not aware of? I'm completely bewildered.

Update: I think another possibility is fret buzz

Comment: It is indeed a fret buzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I was confused about the same thing while listening to the song so I just ordered a transcription for this song from paidtabs.com to clear my mind and it was fret buzz.

Comment: How's the quality of the tab? I might buy it if it's very accurate. If you recommend it, can you share the link to it please?

Comment: Yeah, it was very accurate, but can't see it on their website! maybe you have to request it. check out this link: https://paidtabs.com/search/S33tWZqXhnk

Answer (score 4):

Based on my own experience playing guitar, and with Jarek.D agreeing in the comments, it's safe to assume that it's fret buzz. The amplitude of the sound indicates a large amplitude in the movement of the string, increasing the probability of fret buzz occurring. That, coupled with the lack of any other plausible explanation, makes fret buzz the clear answer.